# Notepad как объеденить строки

Tags: строки, notepad++

Есть список такого плана:

```
45823857892
вася
петя
катя
4589-2349000-4
ваня
саша
```

Нужно сделять сначала номер телефона в строке потом имя:

```
45823857892вася;петя;катя

4589-2349000-4ваня;саша
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь инструментом "замена", там есть опция поиска по регулярному выражению. Составляете регулярное выражение (что-то вроде `([\d\-]+)\n(\w+)\n(\w+)\n(\w+)\n`), в строке замены пишете что-то вроде `$1$2;$3;$4\n`, для проверки перед заменой нажмите "Найти", если ок, то "заменить всё", если не ок -  править регулярку.

Comment: не получилось, регулярное выражение не срабатывает.

Comment: А у вас после числа ещё не всегда одинаковое количество имен?

Comment: В регулярке ``\n`` нужно заменит на ``\r\n`` (т.к. виндовс), возможно еще что-нибудь подправить. И курсор должен стоять в начале файла.

Answer (score 0):

- Сделайте замену `\r\n` на `\n` (с использованием спецсимволов). Внешне ничего не должно измениться. Этим вы приведёте пренос строк к единому формату
- Замена регулярного выражения `\d\n` на `$1` - Так вы удалите перенос строк после числа
- Замена регулярного выражения `([ёа-я])\n([ёа-я])` на `$1;$2` - так вы замените перенос строк между буквами на знак `;`
- Если перенос строк должен быть в windows-формате, сделайте замену `\n` на `\r\n`